# Prove $B-(B-A) = A \cap B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-explanation

English is not my mother language so please forgive any mistakes. I'm not really sure how to approach this question. This is what I have until now:
Consider $x \in B-(B-A)$.
This means $x \in B$ **and** $x\notin(B-A)$. Therefore, $x \in B$ **and** $(x \notin B$ **or** $x \in A)$. Since $x \in B$, $x \in B$ **and** $x \in A$. So $x \in A \cap B$.
However, if I remember correctly, I am supposed to prove the equalty both ways, like this:
1) $B-(B-A) \subset A \cap B$
2) $A \cap B \subset B-(B-A)$

What I just wrote was Part 1 (although I don't know if it's correct). My issue is, I don't really know how to prove Part 2.

Comment: If $x \in A \cap B$, then $x$ is in both $A$ and $B$.  Therefore, $x$ is not in $(B - A)$.  To summarize what we have so far: $x$ is in $B$ **and** is not in  $B - A$.  Therefore $x$ is in $B - (B-A)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove the second part, we have $x \in A \cap B$ therefore $x \in A$ and $x \in B$. Obviously therefore $x \not \in (B-A)$. Since $x \in B$ and $x \not \in (B-A)$ we have that $x \in B - (B-A)$, as desired.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:
If $x \in A \cap B$ then $x \in B$ and $x \not \in (B-A)$.

Answer (score 0):

Working with the [complements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)) might be easier. Note that
$B-A=B\cap A^c$ and thus 
$$
B-(B-A)=B\cap(B\cap A^c)^c
$$
But by [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)#Properties_2):
$$
(B\cap A^c)^c=B^c\cup A.
$$

Now it should be easy to show that (by the [distribution law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)#Algebraic_properties))
$$
B\cap (B^c\cup A)=B\cap A.
$$

Answer (score -1):

$$B-(B-A)=B \cap (B \cap A^C)^C=B \cap (B^C \cup A)= B \cap A=A\cap B$$